# Integral of sine reciprocal

Tags: integration, trigonometry, absolute-value

This might be obvious but I cant see it. I have found that this integral holds $2\int \frac{1}{\sin(2x)} =-\ln(\cot(x))$. I read in a paper that this can be written as $2\int \frac{1}{\sin(2x)} =-\ln(\cot(x))=\ln |\tan(x)|$. I cant see where the absolute value comes from. I get: $2\int \frac{1}{\sin(2x)} =-\ln(\cot(x))=\ln(\cot(x)^{-1})=\ln (\tan(x))$ with no absolute value.

Comment: Whenever you integrate anything to get a log, there will always be an absolute value because $\int \frac{1}{x}dx \to \log|x|$

Comment: Ninad is correct. If anything, the absolute value should have been there from when $\cot$ was introduced. Note that $\frac{2}{\sin\left(2x\right)}$ is finite over $(\pi/2,\pi)$ so it must also be integrable but $\cot x$ is negative there so $\ln \cot x$ would be undefined, which isn't what we want.

Comment: Thanks Ninad and Jam.